# How do I redirect to a url from a micronaut controller?

Tags: java, groovy, micronaut

I have a controller which accepts some params process it and should return a param back to UI by redirecting to a given url.

I have tried `HttpResponse.seeOther` and `HttpResponse.redirect` both displays bank page and "see other" message but does not redirect to an existing servable page. What am I missing here?

```
@Post('/getServ')
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
HttpResponse<String> serve(@Nullable @Body LinkedHashMap payload) {
    //...
    URI location = new URI(redirectURL)
        return HttpResponse.redirect(location).
            header("Location", redirectURL).
            status(302).
            header("JWT", jwt.toString())
    //...
}
```

The expected result should be a redirection to a url from the controller.

Answer (score 4):

Have not tried it, but this should work:

```
@Post('/getServ')
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
HttpResponse<String> serve(@Nullable @Body LinkedHashMap payload) {
    //...
    URI location = new URI(redirectURL)
        return HttpResponse.redirect(location).
            header("JWT", jwt.toString())
    //...
}
```

Your endpoint does not produce `text/html` - the redirect is an empty response with just the `Location` header set (by the framework). However, returning that (`Content-Type`) header may confuse your browser.

You should also not need to additionally set the status code and the location header directly.

Comment: This change did not work. it still shows `303 See Other` or `302` based on seeOther and redirect methods, but does not show redirected page.